# Configuration Preprocessor and conditional statements

Tags: cruisecontrol.net

I am trying to set a conditional statement to use an attribute depending on its value.
I am not sure `ccnet-config` supports conditions

For example:

```
<cb:define project-name="$(name)" />
<cb:if test:"$(project-name == '')">
    <cb:define project-name="$(name)" />
</cb:if>
```

Answer (score 1):

The CruiseControl.NET pre-processor, as of version 1.5, doesn't support conditional statements, so this is not possible.

Answer (score 1):

1.6 support this, and a few other new constructs (see [the preprocessor documentation](http://confluence.public.thoughtworks.org/display/CCNET/Configuration+Preprocessor), new features are towards the bottom)